# Navigator in HighStock chart doesn't work properly after drilldown

Tags: highcharts

Found this chart which has the same problem as mine:

http://jsfiddle.net/8sy0nse4/

When you load it, use the buttons to switch the range and you see the navigator range change too. But after a drilldown it doesn't work properly. You can switch between YTD, 1Y and All but the navigator range doesn't change.

Is there a way to fix this?

Tried this too

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drilldown.src.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by not updating navigator serie. You can fix that, by extracting points (during drilldown event) and apply them into navigator serie. Last step is call update() on the navigator axis to fix extremes.

```
    function navCorrection(e) {

      var chart = this,
        data = e.seriesOptions.data,
        len = data.length - 1,
        nav = chart.scroller;

      nav.series.update({
        data: data
      }, false);

      var min = chart.xAxis[0].dataMin,
        max = min + len * e.seriesOptions.pointInterval;

      chart.xAxis[1].update({
        min: min,
        max: max
      });
  }
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/pdL09y8n/

Comment: First of all: thank you.. But in your example it still doesn't work. 1. Open your fiddle and select different ranges with the range-selector ( -> navigator range changes properly). 2. Do a drilldown and go back. 3. Use the range-selector again (chart range changes but the navigator-extremes doesn't react at all)